# What use is a blue buff for a champion using energy (or anything but mana)

Tags: league-of-legends

The blue buff is known for being the buff that gives you extra mana regen, making you able to cast over and over again.

I just saw in a pro game a Lee Sin jungler take blue at a point where he should really have left it to his mid laner (15 minutes in).

So what advantages does an energy based champion gain with the blue buff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The blue buff, also called the [Crest of Insight](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crest_of_Insight) doesn't just give you mana regen. The full description of the buff is:

> This unit regens 5 flat mana (or energy) and 1% of maximum mana (or 0.5% of maximum energy) per second, has 10% cooldown reduction on their abilities.

So, Lee Sin does gain benefits of energy regen and cooldown reduction. This applies to any energy user, and manaless champions still gain the 10% cooldown reduction provided they are not at the 40% (45% with masteries) cooldown reduction cap.

Also, sometimes it is better for the jungler to take blue buff instead of giving it to their mid laner, if it is in danger of being stolen, if the mid laner is weak to the point that giving them the blue buff will most likely result in the other mid laner getting blue from killing your mid laner, or if the jungler is behind and needs the experience and gold to stay relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Blue buff not only regenerates mana, it also gives you extra energy regen and in addition to that there's the 10% CDR:

> This unit regens 5 flat mana (or energy) and 1% of maximum mana (or 0.5% of maximum energy) per second, has 10% cooldown reduction on their abilities. If slain, this buff transfers to the killer.

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crest_of_Insight)

Note that Blue will also give you a bit of experience/gold. While it's usually not too big of a difference it's better on carry-type champions than on certain junglers.